# Deploy files to a directory with a custom structure in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, directory-structure

I have number of file objects which I would like to redeploy to a directory with a new structure based on requirements stated by the user.

As example could be having these file objects:

```
1)root\name\date\type\filename
2)root\name\date\type\filename
3)root\name\date\type\filename
```

...that I want to save (or a copy of them) in a new structure like below after the user defined a need to split type->date->name:

```
1)root\type\date\name\filename
2)root\type\date\name\filename
3)root\type\date\name\filename
```

... or even losing levels such as:

```
1)root\type\filename
2)root\type\filename
3)root\type\filename
```

I can only come up with the option to go the long way round, taking the initial list and though a process of filtering simply deploy in the new calculated folder structure using basic string operations.

I feel though that someone has probably done this before in a smart way and potentially that a library/module already exists to do this. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you are in UNIX environment, the simpler way to achieve this will be using shell script with `cp` command.

For example, for copying all files from: */root/name/date/type/filename* as */root/date/filename*; you need to just do:

```
cp /root/*/date/*/filename /root/date/filename
```

OR, if you want to move the file, use `mv` command:

```
mv /root/*/date/*/filename /root/date/filename
```

You may run these commands via Python as well using [`os.system()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system) as:

```
import os
os.system("cp \root\*\date\*\filename root\date\filename")
```

For details, check: [Calling an external command in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python)

---

**Edit** based on comment. For copying */root/name/date/type/filename* into */root/date/name/type/filename*, you need to just do:

```
cp /root/name/date/type/filename /root/date/name/type/filename
```

But make sure that directory */root/date/name/type* exists before doing it. In order to make sure it exists, and if not create a directory by using `mkdir` with `-p` option as:

```
mkdir -p /root/date/name/type
```

Comment: OK this could work but i still have questions. What are the * for in your example above? How would you use this method to turn  /root/name/date/type/filename into  /root/date/name/type/filename?

Comment: `*` means anoything in between. Check my edit for details

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using Python `glob`:

The current levels are: name, date, type and filename:

```
curr_levels = "name\\date\\type\\filename"
curr_levels = curr_levels.split("\\")
```

The user want other levels: type, date, name and filename:

```
user_levels = "type\\date\\name\\filename"
user_levels = user_levels.split("\\")
```

We can use `glob.iglob` to iterate the tree structure on 4 levels.
The glob pattern is something like: `<src_dir>\*\*\*\*` (but, we use a more generic way here).

The user structure can be defined with a simple string format.
For instance: `{type}\{date}\{name}\{filename}` on Windows.
Wee need to create the directory structure first and then copy (or move) the file.

```
pattern = os.path.join(source_dir, *("*" * len(curr_levels)))
fmt = os.sep.join(['{{{key}}}'.format(key=key) for key in user_levels])

for source_path in glob.iglob(pattern):
    source_relpath = os.path.relpath(source_path, source_dir)
    parts = source_relpath.split(os.sep)
    values = dict(zip(curr_levels, parts))
    target_relpath = fmt.format(**values)
    target_path = os.path.join(target_dir, target_relpath)
    parent_dir = os.path.dirname(target_path)
    if not os.path.exists(parent_dir):
        os.makedirs(parent_dir)
    shutil.copy2(source_path, target_path)
```

Note: if your `source_dir` is the same as `target_dir` (the `root` in your question), you need to replace `glob.iglob` by `glob.glob` in order to store the whole list of files in memory before processing. This is required to avoid `glob.iglob` browse the directory tree you are creating…